# PowerBI: How to "transpose" matrix visualization?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix in PowerBI that I would like to "transpose" to visualize the data differently. Does anyone know how this could be done?

In the pictures, the first one is my current solution and the second one is the desired layout. So I would need to "turn the matrix sideways". I would not like to transform, transpose or unpivot the source data if possible so I'm searching for a visual change.

[image: Here is my current solution]

[image: This is kind of the desired outcome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the Matrix Format Visual > `Values` > `Options` > `Switch values in row groups rather than columns`.
2. Move your `SalesDate` from Rows well to Columns well.